# What is the best way in node to get a change of the hour?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events

I could periodically check every 10 minutes or so but this could fire 9:59 minutes later. 
I think it would be more performant if I could just listen to a datetime change event.

Is there anything similar to this that I didn't find or any practical workaround?

Comment: Can you give a little more context surrounding your use case? Have you considered leveraging something like [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)?

Comment: @esqew I want my program to run as a service and want some code to be triggered when it gets night time/ day time. Node-cron looks promising, I'll have a deeper look into it!

Answer (score 1):

Determine how long it is until the top of the next hour, then set a timeout for that duration of time.

```
const hours = Date.now() / 3600000;
const sleepMillis = (Math.ceil(hours) - hours) * 3600000;

setTimeout(() => doYourThing(), sleepMillis);
```

Note: A little more care is necessary to make this code work in timezones that aren't offset a whole number of hours from UTC.

Comment: Very clever! Too simple that I could make this myself I guess :D if I find nothing "better" I'll definitely use this, thanks